# Is it a good practice to create a completely isolated virtual python environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, dependencies, virtual-environment

I have created a conda environment named neuralnets. When I print sys.path I see this:

['C:\Users\distef\Desktop\cuda tests', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\DLLs', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\lib', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets', '', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\neuralnets\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

there is one path which is not in the neuralnets folder(excluding the scripts folder) named:

'C:\Users\distef\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages

My question is why?
Why the environment is not completely isolated?
Won't this create dependency problems if a undesirable package from that folder is imported? Shouldn't this path at least be final element of the list?
What would be a best practice in this case?

chatGPT response: Avoid using pip in Conda environments: If possible, try not to use pip within your Conda environment. Instead, rely on Conda for package management. If you need a package that is not available via Conda or Conda Forge, consider creating a separate virtual environment using venv or virtualenv and use pip within that environment.

I have used pip once in this environment due to an error of the jupyterlab which wanted a package named chardet (I couldn't install it with conda install)